# value not added to dict using int boolean decision mysteriously - python

Tags: python, dictionary, boolean

I am trying to increment values to 4 dictionaries here (the dictionary is di_A1, di_A2, di_B1, di_B2).

I am checking lines in a file at positions 3-9 in for the first name of the parent, then position 11 for the sex, and 12-14 for the age.

Position 11 will always be 1 or 2. 1 - male, 2 - female.
Position 12-14 will contain a number from 001 > 150 for age.

The first of those characters determines if the "parent" should be saved to an A or B dictionary. The remaining 3 values determine the age of the parent, which are grouped into values of over or under 50 years of age.

dictionaries:

di_A1 stores dad names, under 50;

di_A2 stores dad names, over 50;

di_B1 stores mom names, under 50;

di_B2 stores mom names, over 50;

Later I print these to a .csv file in these 5 columns:

first name

count of dads 50 or under

count of dads 50 or over

count of moms 50 or under

count of moms 50 or over

The very first piece where I save them to the dictionary is not working. I think it's when I check the age value that is broken.

def main():

```
import re # I use this later, but maybe I should be using it here?

# find all files to check 
filelist = glob.glob("FOLDER/subfolder/names*/*.TXT")

di_A1 = {}
di_A2 = {}
di_B1 = {}
di_B2 = {}

for file in filelist: 
    infile = open(file,"r")
    for line in infile:
        sex_age = int(line[10:14]) #11 stores sex, 12-14 store age
        firstname = line[2:9] # 3-9 store first name

        if (sex_age < 1051) : #if male 50 or under
            di_A1[firstname] = di_A1.get(firstname,0) + 1
        elif (sex_age < 1150) : #if male 50 or over
            di_A2[firstname] = di_A2.get(firstname,0) + 1
        elif (sex_age < 2051) : #if female 50 or under
            di_B1[firstname] = di_B1.get(firstname,0) + 1
        elif (sex_age < 2150) : #if female 50 or over
            di_B2[firstname] = bi_B2.get(firstname,0) + 1

    infile.close()
```

## more after this, but I'm pretty sure that stuff is working

Right now, nothing is saved in any of the dictionaries. What am I doing wrong?

I should note that I was thinking of breaking this down further to more age groups -- 20 and under, 21-35, 36-45, 46-55, 56-65, etc.

Answer (score 0):

... Well, as it turns out, I made a typo in my file path. (Embarrassing, as I've been troubleshooting this all day......)

The program works as shown above.